# Magento 2 - Move the afterMethods item (Discount and Gift Card Code) to the Order Summary sidebar

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, payment, sidebar

I would like to move the `afterMethods` xml item which contains the Discount Code and Gift Card code under the `billing-step` in the `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/checkout_index_index.xml` so that it is displayed below the `shipping-information` item in the `sidebar`

Snippet of the `afterMethods`:

```
<!-- merge your payment methods here -->
<item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">afterMethods</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <!-- merge additional data after payment methods here -->
    </item>
</item>
```

Here is a screenshot of my current `checkout/payment` page: 
[image]

Since it is not a `block` or a `container` I am not quiet sure the proper steps to move the item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in checkout_index_index.xml in your theme for movie discount form in sidebar.

First disable the discount form from its original place, and then call it again where you wish to place.

app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In the same way you can move giftcard.